# Unable to Save extracted OLE file(pdf) from Ms Word showing object error

Tags: vba, ms-word

i tried to save the OLE file(pdf) in MS Word document its open the file successful but while saving it showing "Object doesn't support this property or Method".

in this line i am getting error "objEmbeddedDoc.Save filelocation"

kindly help me on this

```
Sub ExtractAndSaveEmbeddedFiles()
Dim objEmbeddedShape As InlineShape
Dim strShapeType As String, strEmbeddedDocName As String
Dim objEmbeddedDoc As Object
With ActiveDocument
For Each objEmbeddedShape In .InlineShapes 
strShapeType = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.ClassType
objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.Open
  
Set objEmbeddedDoc = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.Object

strEmbeddedDocName = objEmbeddedShape.OLEFormat.IconLabel
filelocation = "D:\Users\UAT\" & strEmbeddedDocName
objEmbeddedDoc.Save filelocation

objEmbeddedDoc.Close

Set objEmbeddedDoc = Nothing

Next objEmbeddedShape
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: The embedded object does not have a `Save` method. Try `Debug.Print TypeName(objEmbeddedDoc)` to discover the runtime type of the object, then lookup its documentation to find the actual member you're looking for.

Comment: Resut for 'Debug.Print TypeName(objEmbeddedDoc)'  is "IAcroAXDoc". Is there any other option to save this file. i want to do this for 600 documents. kindly support me on this

Comment: Cool, that's progress! So, the bad news is that the type is hard to lookup and I couldn't find it with a quick Google search. The good news is that since the type exists on your machine (late binding wouldn't work otherwise), then the library it's defined in also exists in your machine: go to tools/references, and try to locate the type library that contains it - I'd expect it to have a name/description similar to "Adobe Acrobat ActiveX Document Type Library". Reference all libraries that look like they could be it, and then hit F2 to bring up the Object Browser (continued)

Comment: ...and type "IAcroAXDoc" in the search box - if something comes up, you've found the type you're looking for! Browse its members; if a `SaveAs` or `Export` method exists, that's your bad boy!

Comment: "IAcroAXDoc" is not available in object Browser. i tried to add a reference of "Adobe Acrobat ActiveX Document Type Library" but this not available.  i have added "adobe acrobat 10.0 type library", "Acrobat Distiller".  i tried lot possibility on this. still i am in same page.

Comment: I've researched a bit deeper and found that the type might be defined [as follows](https://gist.github.com/stijnsanders/a2b33beb34fefb674300#file-acrobat_tlb-pas-L813-L822); if that's what the interface is defined with, then it has 2 members: `Application`, and `Document`. If we're lucky and the `Document` property returns an instance of [this object](https://gist.github.com/stijnsanders/a2b33beb34fefb674300#file-acrobat_tlb-pas-L424-L462), then the fix would be to change `objEmbeddedDoc.Save filelocation` to `objEmbeddedDoc.Document.Save filelocation`.

Comment: Note that the `.Close` member call would also blow up with error 438; make that `.Document.Close` (note: the method takes a `Boolean` parameter that you are not passing, expect another kind of error if the parameter isn't optional).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon. Thank you for your great support. Still i didn't get any improvement in my coding. shall I share my Word file. could you please help me on this. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gR0yv_zDELbTqohggL2aqes5F3KcSRjJ?usp=sharing

Comment: See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/how-to-extract-embedded-files-from-word-document/6a92bd9a-1ceb-4cf8-bd6f-ebad955cbdc1?page=3